# Можно ли представить 2д гистограмму с 3д-столбцами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Написал простенькую программу, которая рисует обычную 2д гистограмму по введенным данным.

Есть ли способы сделать ее из 3д-столбцов как на прикрепленной картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И доп.вопрос, каким образом можно присваивать каждому столбцу определенный цвет?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = []
l = []
n = int(input('Введите количество столбцов '))
for i in range(n):
    newKey = input('Введите имя столбца ')
    newValue = int(input('Введите значение cтолбца '))
    l.append(newKey)
    x.append(newValue)


y = np.arange(len(x))

plt.bar(y,x, align='center')
plt.xticks(y, l)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать [так](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(np.arange(2006, 2011), 1, 9, 
         0.4, 0.5, np.random.randint(10,50,5),
         alpha=0.1)
```

Результат:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попытался сделать столбцы не такими вытянутыми по оси `Y` и добавить надписи:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = [2006,2007,2008,2009]
y = [0]*len(x); z = [0]*len(x); dx = 0.6; dy = 0.5
dz = [50, 30, 10, 40]
ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='yellow', zorder='max')
# adding labels
for xx,yy,zz in zip(x,y,dz):
    ax.text(xx,yy+dy/2,zz*1.025, str(zz),
            family='monospace', size='larger', weight='bold', color='b')
ax.bar3d(x, 1, z, 0, 0.5, 0, color='white', zorder=-1)
plt.xticks(x, x)
plt.yticks(y, y)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но сломались подписи для оси `Y` и как это починить я пока не нашел...

вот еще вариант со случайными цветами:

```
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
colors = np.random.choice(list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys()), len(x))
ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color=colors, zorder='max')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в принципе, для решения моей задачи значения оси "y" и не нужны, поэтому ваше решение подходит, большое спасибо.

Comment: @badordos, пожалуйста :)